# Accessing nested objects within objects in PHP not working

Tags: php, api, quickbooks

In PHP, I'm requesting data from my QuickBooks Online account using their Query functions.

I'm iterating through each customer object that is returned in a standard foreach($customer as $x) code block.

Using var_dump, I can tell each object has the following format:

```
object(QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPCustomer) [34]
public 'Taxable' => string 'true' (length=4)
public 'BillAddr' =>
    object(QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPCustomer) [78]
    public 'Id' => string '7509' (length=4)
    public 'Line1' => '1234 Irrelevant Dr.' (length=19)
```

In PHP, if I simply try to access $x->Taxable, it works no problem, but *any* sub-object I try to access returns an error: "trying to get property of non-object on line X"

So:

```
echo $x->Taxable;
```

gives me the taxable status, but

```
echo $x->BillAddr->Line1;
```

gives me an error.

These are public classes, so shouldn't I be able to call them like this?

Comment: Whats the result of `var_dump($x->BillAddr);`?

Comment: It returns the ‘BillAddr’ sub-object perfectly as you expect and dumps it out in exactly the same format as var_dump($x); shown above. 

So you’d think $x->BillAddr->Line1 would work, but it doesn’t. 

Even var_dump($x->BillAddr->Line1); dumps out the proper data! But as soon as I try to assign it to a  variable or an array, that error pops up.

Comment: Can you add the dump of `$x->BillAddr` to better assess this?

Comment: Sure. var_dump($x->BillAddr) :

`C:\...\QB.php:62:
object(QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPPhysicalAddress) [78]
public 'Id' => '7509' (length=4)
public 'Line1' => '1234 Irrelevant Dr.' (length=19)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem and I have no idea why this is required, but here's how I got it to work, adding curly braces:

`echo "{$x->BillAddr->Line1}";` instead of just `echo "$x->BillAddr->Line1";`

Same rule applies to assignment as well, apparently:

`$line1 = "{$x->BillAddr->Line1}";`

Thanks for your help, guys!